Angular Route: reload the same page with different state
I'm trying to recharge the same page on Angular (v18) with a different state with this function:
  openForm(form: FormFavoriteElement) {
    form.createDraft = true;
    this.formDataService
      .getFavouriteFormContent(form.acroContentId, 'acro')
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/pdfViewer', {
          onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
          replaceUrl: true,
          skipLocationChange: true,
          state: {
            pdfdata: result,
            data: form,
          },
        });
      });
  }

but what's happend is that at the first try doesn't charge anything, at the second one the new form appear.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong? I thought that maybe I have to clear the state before, but I'm not finding how to do that.
Thank you for your help

Could you share a working example on stackblitz where the issue happens

from this SO "Please be noted that onSameUrlNavigation only executes guards and resolvers but does not reinitialize components."
So, you can define a CustomReuseStrategy in the way
export class CustomReuseStrategy extends BaseRouteReuseStrategy {

  public override shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
                                   curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig && !future.data['reload']
  }
}

Then provide in your app
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy },
    provideRouter(...)
  ],
});

The only is change the routes adding to the path the data:{reload:true} when you want to reload the component.
e.g. your routes defined like
[
  { path: '', component: ProductsComponent },
  { path: 'details', component: ProductComponent, data:{reload:true} },
],

a stackblitz
